# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a error saying that,

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null.
```

but how can i check the element, here is my code

```
$infoArray['groupId'] = $info->getId();
$infoArray['name'] = $info->getName();
$infoArray['addressLine1'] = $info->getAddressLine1();
$infoArray['addressLine2'] = $info->getAddressLine2();
$infoArray['isActive'] = $info->getActive();
$infoArray['countryId'] = $info->getCountry()->getId(); //Here is my error line
$infoArray['countryName'] = $info->getCountry()->getName();
$infoArray['stateId'] = $info->getState()->getId();
$infoArray['stateName'] = $info->getState()->getName();
$infoArray['cityId'] = $info->getCity()->getId();
$infoArray['cityName'] = $info->getCity()->getName();
$infoArray['areaId'] = $info->getArea()->getId();
$infoArray['areaName'] = $info->getArea()->getName();
$infoArray['zipcode'] = $info->getZipcode();
```

Comment: Well, your `$info` object seems to return `null` from the `getCountry()` object. So you need to check with `null !== $info->getCountry()` or something similar first that you get the expected object back before trying to call any method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the line by :

```
$infoArray['countryId'] = $info->getCountry() ? $info->getCountry()->getId() : null;
```

Do the same for each line corresponding to an association (which can be null), and `null` will be returned if the object is null.

Comment: $infoArray['countryId'] = $info->getCountry() ?: $info->getCountry()->getId(); is not working for me, instead $infoArray['countryId'] = $info->getCountry() ? $info->getCountry()->getId() : ''; working for me

Comment: Thanks, is it ok to leave as null or ''

Answer (score 2):

check with is_null($object_name)

Comment: i am looking something similiar to ternary operator, that makes my code clean